# YouTube media filed without remove media button

Tags: 7, entities, media, files

I'm using `Drupal 7`. The Remove media button on youTube media entry (field) is missing. This is for a field with name: `Videos`, field type: `Multimedia asset (deprecated)`, widget: `Media file selector`.

I can add unlimited multimedia entries and the remove button only missing for youtube videos (in case of an image I have the remove button), as shown on the next image:

[image: image and youtube entry in media field]

I'm using the [media 7.x-1.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/media/releases/7.x-1.4) and [Media: YouTube 7.x-2.0-rc4](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube/releases/7.x-2.0-rc4) modules.

Can anyone help me how to fix this? Is this a bug or my mistake?

Here is a link to my issue/bug report: https://www.drupal.org/node/2459947

As I was creating new roles and tested on different browsers, I saw that the removal button is missing when I'm administrator of the site and I'm using chrome browser. With Mozilla as admin I can see the removal button.

With other roles (like content Editor) the button is visible in both browsers.

This post was suggested to be a duplicate and the solution can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2137863